# Proof strategy involving first order logic for existential quantification at very beginning

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I have the following problem from the book "How to Prove it" by Daniel J.Velleman.

Prove that
$$
\exists z\in \mathbb{R} \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^+ \left[\exists y \in \mathbb{R} (y-x=y/x) \leftrightarrow x \neq z \right].
$$

I have no idea how to deal with the existential quantifier at the beginning. I tried to negate it, but the rest is too complicated. Do you have strategic hints how to proceed? Allowed is first-order logic.

EDIT

Based and the response, I would propose the following proof and kindly ask the community to check if it is correct.

*Proof*: Let $z=1$, and let x be some arbitrary real number.

1. $(\rightarrow)$ Suppose $\exists y \in \mathbb{R} (y-x=y/x)$ and choose $y_0$ to be some real number such that $(y_0-x=y_0/x)$. Suppose $x=z$. Since $x=z$ and $z=1$, $x=1$. However, plugging $x=1$ into $y_0-x=y_0/x$ yields a contradiction, and thus, $x\neq z$. Hence, $\exists y \in \mathbb{R} (y-x=y/x) \rightarrow x \neq z$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, it follows that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^+ \left[\exists y \in \mathbb{R} (y-x=y/x) \rightarrow x \neq z \right]$.
2. ($\leftarrow$) Suppose $x \neq z$. Since $z=1$, $x \neq 1$. Let $y_0=\frac{x^2}{x-1}$, which is defined because $x \neq 1$. Plugging into the equation $y_0-x=y_0/x$, we can verify that the equation holds for this particular value $y_0$. Hence, $x \neq z \rightarrow \exists y \in \mathbb{R} (y-x=y/x)$. Since x was arbitrary, it follows that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^+ \left[\exists y \in \mathbb{R} (y-x=y/x) \leftarrow x \neq z \right]$.

Therefore, the theorem follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to prove $\exists z\in \mathbb R\,\cdots $ is always to show a *particular* number $z$ with the given property. So before you can start writing down a proof, you will need to *find* such a number.

More precisely, the statement to be proved has the form
$$ \exists z.\forall x.(P(x)\leftrightarrow x\ne z) $$
which says that all $x$ *except exactly one* have the property $P(x)$. -- Or, since $x$ is restricted to *positive* numbers, perhaps all $x$ do have the property $P(x)$, in which case $z=-42$ will work.

So you're looking for the unique $x$ such that the equation $y-x=y/x$ does *not* have a solution for $y$, **or** for a proof that $y-x=y/x$ has a solution for every positive $x$.

Comment: Thank you Henning for you hint. I added the (supposed) proof in an edit. It would be great if you could have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Velleman provides a template for these. For example (broadly paraphrased):

> To prove $\exists z (\ldots)$, write:
>   Let $z =$ [some value you decide on]. [Then prove $\ldots$]
>
> To prove $\forall x (\ldots)$, write:
>   Let $x$ be arbitrary. [Then prove $\ldots$]
>
> To prove $P \leftrightarrow Q$, prove $P \rightarrow Q$ and $Q \rightarrow P$.
>
> To prove $P \rightarrow Q$, write: Suppose $P$. [Then prove $Q$.]
>
> To use $\exists y (\ldots)$, use the fact that there's some $y_0$ which satisfies $\ldots$

So the structure of your proof is going to be:

> Let $z =$ [some real number you decide on]. Let $x$ be an arbitrary positive real number.
>
> Suppose $\exists y\in\mathbb{R}(y-x = y/x)$. Consider $y_0$ which satisfies this. Thus $y_0 - x = y_0/x$. [Now prove $x \neq z$.]
>
> Suppose $x \neq z$. Let $y =$ [some real number you decide on, possibly depending on $x$]. [Now prove $y-x=y/x$.]

So you can see what you need to do. You need to find a value $z$ such that you'll be able to complete the rest of the proof. For the second paragraph, you'll need to be able to use $y_0-x = y_0/x$ to prove $x$ is not equal to $z$. And in the third paragraph you'll need to use $x \neq z$ to prove that you can find $y$ such that $y-x=y/x$.

So to figure out a $z$ that will work (i.e. let you complete the proof), you need to see for what values of $x$ you can solve $y-x = y/x$ (for $y$, with $x$ fixed). If there's one value of $x$ that gives you trouble, set $z$ to be that, then fill in the details for the proof.

Comment: Thank you aes, I was already busy with the proof in an edit when you wrote your answer. That's basically confirming what I did, I guess.

Comment: @Dominik Your edit looks good, though I would spell out the contradiction in the second paragraph a bit more (plug in $1$ etc). Also, in the third paragraph, I would do out the algebra to check the equation is true when you plug in your value for $y$.

Comment: Yes you're right, I actually checked it, but abbreviated it for succinctness. Thanks a lot.