# clarification of a logic proof

Tags: logic

I am a bit confused on what this question is asking me to prove:

Prove $$
\exists z\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^{+}[\exists y(y - x = y/x)\leftrightarrow x \neq z] 
$$

Am I asked to prove that there exists a z where the bi-conditional statement is true? Or is z a given and I should just prove the statement in the brackets for some z?

I put that thought aside and showed that the statement in brackets is true when z = 1, but I just want to be sure that I did what the question I was asked.

Comment: Well, stupid gold badge superpowers ... hmm, hey guys, this exercise was previously discussed as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1167153/; perhaps the question ought to be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: My bad! I didn't realize the question was previously asked.

Comment: x @Stefan: I don't think you could reasonably be expected to know; I only found the earlier question because I remembered answering it and could search for some specific phrases from it.

Answer (score 2):

It is conventional that quantifiers bind from left to right.  Therefore, to prove this statement, you must first choose a $z$.  Then, your adversary picks an $x$, and regardless of this choice, you must now prove that the biconditional holds.

To do so you must prove that under certain circumstances $y$ exists, and under other circumstances it does not.

Answer (score 0):

This question is from Velleman's [How to Prove it?](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521675995) (1994). There is no secret:

You are asked to prove that there exists a $z \in \mathbb{R}^+$ that, for all $z \in \mathbb{R}^+$, the biconditional statement

$$∃y∈\mathbb{R}(y−x=y/x)↔x≠z$$

is true. Then we just recall what Velleman says about proving quantified sentences:

> **To prove a goal of the form $∀x P(x)$**:
>
> Let *x* stand for an arbitrary object and prove *P(x)*. The letter *x* must be a new variable in the proof. If *x* is already being used in the proof to stand for something, then you must choose an unused variable, say *y*, to stand for the arbitrary object, and prove $P(y)$.

and

> **To prove a goal of the form $∃x P(x)$:**
>
> Try to find a value of *x* for which you think $P(x)$ will be true. Then start your proof with “Let *x* = (the value you decided on)” and proceed to prove
>   $P(x)$ for this value of *x*. Once again, *x* should be a new variable.

This means that, for the outer universal quantifier, *x* must be an arbitrary (new) variable and, for the out-most existential quantifier you must chose a value $z=a$ for it. You should prove the universal quantifier before, and the existential next.

Indeed, the structure of the main sentence you have to prove is of a biconditional, which means you proof should have more or less the following structure:

1. Let $z=a \in \mathbb{R}^+$ (whatever value you need for it).
2. Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$

   - Proof of $\Rightarrow$
   - Proof of $\Leftarrow$
3. Proof of $\forall$
4. Proof of $\exists$